# Issue with rendering angular material components

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm not able to render simple angular material components even after including all the necessary dependencies.
HTML

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" layout="row">
<md-button>Button</md-button>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']);
```

Here's the link with all the dependencies included: 
https://jsfiddle.net/rxby6cac/3/

Confused... What's the issue with this simple code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/rxby6cac/10/)... it was fine, the problem was the load type (see picture below). You have to change it to load type `no wrap - <body>`.
***Additionally, I've note that your are using a angular material RC (Release Candidate) version. As a advice try to use a stable version ([move to 1.1.3](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-material)).*** 
[image]